# Changing cursor outside application

Tags: java, cursor, awt, mouse

I was wondering, is it possible to change mouse cursor image outside my Java application window?

I already found out how to make custom cursor images, and how to change it on components, but in my application I need for cursor to be changed all the time, even when my `JFrame` is minimized. I already Googled and searched a lot, but didn't manage to find anything that suits my needs.

If I was unclear please do ask for explanation, it's my first post here so I probably didn't write my question that well.

Comment: *"..in my application I need for cursor to be changed all the time, even when my `JFrame` is minimized."*  Why?  Explain it to me like I was a potential user and it was part of a feature that might persuade me to ***pay*** for the app.

Comment: Ok, it goes like this: I have a client - sever type of application, client side is on android, server is on pc. I am transmiting accelerometer data to move my mouse cursor on pc and it's working well. What I noticed is that i cannot see cursor that well when i am far away from my monitor (which is one of the reasons I am making that app), so I thought of changing cursor size and/or image to something I can see better from a distance. So the main idea i want to be able to control my pc from far away, but I cannot see cursor or it's blending in the background.